# Script in JavaScript and PHP - variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php script which shows me all folders - categories on my website:

```
echo "<ul>";
    foreach(glob('category/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
        $dir = str_replace('category/', '', $dir);
        echo '<li class="button" onclick="reload();">'.$dir.'</li>';
    }; 
echo "</ul>";
```

When I click on category JQuery reload a div with content of php file.

```
function reload(category) {
    $("#content").load("send.php");
}
```

I want to send to that php file name of the category I have had clicked. How can I do that?
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
echo "<ul>";
    foreach(glob('category/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
                    $dir = str_replace('category/', '', $dir);
                        echo '<li class="button" onclick="reload(\''.$dir.\'');">'.$dir.'</li>';
                }; 
    echo "</ul>";
```

I added the $dir variable as a parameter of the reload function.

And then inside your reload function :

```
function reload(category) {
    $("#content").load("send.php?category="+category);
}
```

Is this what you meant ?
Hope it helped :)

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not work for me. I have an error "Undefined index: category" when i call <?php echo $_GET['category']; ?>

Comment: Maybe because it echo this : onclick="reload(category);", but it should echo this : onclick="reload('category');"
See my edit on the first code snippet

Comment: Yes! Great, it works i replaced reload with that reload(\''.$dir.'\') and now it wortks. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Nice ;)
Have a great day !